# Why my map function not working on filter dates?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, filter, fetch-api

I am calling a fetch API data and create table on HTML body load. and filter and map method giving right data but when I am selecting the dates from input and then this is only return the dates but somehow filter and map method not working with those dates criteria. I tried to debug but no luck don't know where is the problems is, struggling to find where is issue.

HTML

```html
<div class="row mt-5 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 d-flex mt-3">
        <h5 style="margin-right: 1rem;">Filter</h5>
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="filter">
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
            <option value="" selected>Pending</option>
            <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
            <option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</option>
          </select>       
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 d-flex flex-row justify-content-end align-items-center mt-3">
        <h5>From</h5>
        <input type="date" class="dates" id="filterStart">
        <h5>To</h5>
        <input type="date" class="dates" id="filterEnd">
        <button type="button" onclick="getDates()">Refresh</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```js
function getDates() {
  let filterStart = document.getElementById("filterStart").value;
  let startDate = "";
  let endDate = "";
  if (!filterStart) {
    let date = new Date();
    startDate = new Date(
      date.getFullYear(),
      date.getMonth(),
      1
    ).toLocaleDateString();
    endDate = new Date(
      date.getFullYear(),
      date.getMonth() + 1,
      0
    ).toLocaleDateString();
  } else {
    startDate = new Date(
      document.getElementById("filterStart").value
    ).toLocaleDateString();
    endDate = new Date(
      document.getElementById("filterEnd").value
    ).toLocaleDateString();
  }
  getLeaveData(startDate, endDate);
}

function getLeaveData(startDate, endDate) {
  console.log(startDate, endDate);
  console.log(typeof startDate);
  let status = document.getElementById("filter").value;
  fetch(getLeaves)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      let tableData = "";
      let id = 0;
      let table = data
        .filter((values) => {
          return (
            values.startDate >= startDate &&
            values.startDate <= endDate &&
            values.hrremarks == status
          );
        })
        .map((values) => {
          console.log(values);
          tableData += `
                <tr id=${id++}>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.employeeId}</th>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.firstName} ${
            values.LastName
          }</th>                  
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.email}</th>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.leaveType}</th>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.duration}</th>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.startDate}</th>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.enddate}</th>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;">${values.hrremarks}</th>
                    <th style="font-weight: normal;"><button type="button" >Action</button></th>
                    </tr>`;
        });
      document.getElementById("dataTable").innerHTML = tableData;
    });
}
```

Comment: Try converting your dates into JS Date objects, you may be comparing strings which will give you unexpected results.

Comment: @bluecouch hey, thank for the comment i tried this but not working its providing same data also now it not even rendering the table..

Answer (score 0):

Finally Struggling a lot. I found the correct way. which is working fine. I just used getTime() method.